# Content Type usages

Tags: content-type

The following code just gives me the URL of the site collection. However I need to be able to determine which list is using this content type. Do I need iterate through splistitemcollection?

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://portal.brisk.tea/sites/GreenTea");
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{    
  $ctype = $web.ContentTypes["NewTeaSample"]
  $usages = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ctype)    
  foreach ($usage in $usages)
  {
       Write-Host $usage.Url
  }
}
```

Comment: I added $ctuse.IsUrlToList method and it returns false. Does this mean the content type in question is not hooked any list for the given site collection?

Comment: I am trying to delete a content type and it's telling me it's been in use but the scripts tell me otherwise.

Comment: how many results do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure there aren't any sub content type that is using or inheriting from this content type. if yes, delete the child CT that inherits from this and then delete the CT in question.

-- if above does not help then you may want to try these steps ---

1. Clean your recycle bin as there may be list or library RB that is/r using this content type.
2. Then try to delete the CT.

Comment: Perfect. You step 1 helped like magic. There was a child CT that was inheriting from this CT. I delete the child CT, then Parent CT became delete friendly. Thanks Mary.

Answer (score 0):

If the content type was used in a list, the `$usage.Url` will be same as SPList's `RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` and `$usage.IsUrlToList` will be true. Hope this helps you.

Comment: But CT is not in use in any library but code returns the url /sites/GreenTea and Isurltolist is false. I am trying to delete the CT and getting ct in use error.

Comment: This makes sense because /sites/GreenTea appears to be a site (root web) and not a list.